# Jquery dynamic element selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this question has been answered a lot, but when I applied this solution  [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1207393/6063955) the selector selects all the elements and retrieved only the first element

```
$('body').on('click','a.delete',function() {
   var id = $('a.delete').attr('id');
   var par = $('a.delete').closest('.foo');
   console.log(id);
   par.hide();
   postDelete(id);
});
```

`.foo` is a parent element of `a.delete`
this code hides all elements with class `.foo` and delete the first element with class `a.delete` not the clicked one

How can I retrieve the ID of the element I clicked and hide its parent?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `this` instead of `a.delete` in click event to get the reference of clicked `a.delete` like following.

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.delete', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id'); //change here
    var par = $(this).closest('.foo'); //change here
    console.log(id);
    par.hide();
    postDelete(id);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this` to get the `clicked` element.

From the [*docs*](https://learn.jquery.com/events/inside-event-handling-function/), *In addition to the event object, the event handling function also has access to the DOM element that the handler was bound to via the keyword `this`*

```js
$('body').on('click', 'a.delete', function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var par = $(this).closest('.foo');
  console.log(id);
  par.hide();
  postDelete(id);
});
```